# Css linear gradient showing zigzag

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Trying to make a background color for my body element using  linear gradient but it ends up showing a zigzag

I tried using this code, for example

```
Body{
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, Blue 50%, red 50%)
}
```

I got this:

[image]

But this is what I was expecting
[image: background image]

Comment: Cannot replicate - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VwyPMyJ

Comment: We need the code context to help you. Looks like some repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first give the `body` a `height:100vh;` and replace the `45deg` with `to bottom left`
because it won't work well when you shrink the screen

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  height:100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, red 50%, blue 50%)
}
```